# gradle task only running last command

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I have this task, which copy some files to a device

```
task copyTestVideos(type: Exec) {
  commandLine 'adb', 'push', 'src/androidTest/raw/test1.mp4', '/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/'
  commandLine 'adb', 'push', 'src/androidTest/raw/test2.mp4', '/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/'
  commandLine 'adb', 'push', 'src/androidTest/raw/test3.mp4', '/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/'
  commandLine 'adb', 'push', 'src/androidTest/raw/test4.mp4', '/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/'
  commandLine 'adb', 'push', 'src/androidTest/raw/test5.mp4', '/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/'
  commandLine 'adb', 'push', 'src/androidTest/raw/test6.mp4', '/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/'
}
```

turns out that only the last line seems to be executed. Anyone saw something similar?

Comment: May be you need to put a wait before copying next video.

Comment: `commandLine` is not performing operation per se, it just setting the properties of your task to indicate which command should be executed. Not sure how to execute several commands though.

Comment: Sorry I dont know, I just guess it.

Comment: well, nevermind, copied the folder `raw` instead files worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is **configuring** your `Exec` task. The lines starting with `commandLine` are not actually executing during the configuration phase. Instead they set property `commandLine` of your task repeatedly.

During the execution phase property `commandLine` is used to start the process. At this moment it only contains one value: the strings of the last line above.

See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases

Switching to copying the folder like you did is the simplest solution in this case.